# How to configure Eclipse to break on a file?

Tags: java, eclipse, breakpoints

How can one configure Eclipse Luna to break on a source file? I have a complex Java program where the flow of execution moves between several source files and JARs, but I am only concerned with the behavior of one particular source file.

I want to step through every line of code in this particular file, and skip all other code in the project.

I could get the desired behavior by manually setting a breakpoint on every line in the target file, but that would be tedious for my 740 line file.

Is there any way to restrict the debugger to a single source file or programmatically set breakpoints on every line of the file or run until a line from a specific file is encountered?

Comment: You just need to find the entry point in your particular source file and place a debug point there....

Comment: Flow passes in and out of the file I want to debug to other files that I don't care about. A single breakpoint is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a breakpoint in the file you want to debug.  When Eclipse stops at the breakpoint, press <kbd>F6</kbd> to go line by line, so you stay in the same line.

[Teach fishing](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)

Comment: I'm not looking just to break in the file. What I want is to be able to step over all code that is not part of the file when stepping. The file calls into and is called from code that I don't care about. There is a lot of code that I don't care about and don't want to step through to get back to the code I do care about.

Comment: @Techrocket9 - If you don't care about other files, then your breakpoints in those files should be disabled.  This is possible in `Breakpoints` view of Eclipse.

Comment: I don't have any breakpoints set in other files. But if I am stepping in the file I care about eventually I step into a file I don't care about through a call into that code from within my file. I can't step over this call because eventually the code I do not care about will call another function in the file I do care about.

Comment: Don't `Step Into`, use `Step Over`.  Don't `F5`, do `F6`.

Comment: If I Step Over I will miss execution of parts of my code that occur when the code I do not care about calls a function in my code (there are many possible functions it can call).

Comment: @Techrocket9 - I got you. AFAIK, no such solution exists.